# Generating marginal prediction confidence intervals from a glmer object using predictInterval() from merTools

Tags: r, predict, lme4

I am trying to generate confidence intervals for marginal predictions using the `predictInterval` function which is [further described here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/Using_predictInterval.html).

Herein I use the `goats` data from the ResourceSelection package, which contains used and available locations (coded 1 and 0, respectively) and values of covariates of interest (e.g. elevation, slope, etc.) to build a reproducible model.

Packages

```
library(lme4)
library(ResourceSelection)
library(merTools)
```

The df contains used and available locations for 10 animals.

```
table(goats$ID, goats$STATUS)
       0    1
  1  1404  702
  2  1112  556
  3  1026  513
  4   634  317
  5  1272  636
  6  1456  728
  7  1394  697
  8  1468  734
  9  1608  804
  10 1302  651
```

Below is a example model with a random intercept specified for individual (ID). the covariates are centered and scaled within the model fit using `scale()`.

```
 mod <- glmer(STATUS ~ scale(ELEVATION) + scale(SLOPE) + scale(ET) + scale(HLI) + (1|ID),
             family=binomial, data = goats, verbos = 1) 
summary(mod)
```

I now want to predict over a range of ELEVATION with all other covariates at  their mean.  Because I am working with scaled and centered covariates, the mean is 0. The min and max of scale(ELEVATION) is -1.97056 and 2.52926, which I use to make the new predict data below.

```
PredDat <- data.frame(ELEVATION = seq(-1.97056, 2.52926, length.out = 1000),
                      SLOPE = 0,
                      ET = 0,
                      HLI = 0)
```

While I can generate predictions manually, I am not sure how to estimate the 95 percent CI's when large data sets make bootstrap methods ([recommended here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lme4/docs/predict.mermod)) prohibitive. Is it possible to generate marginal predictions and CI's with the `predictInterval` function without accounting for the individual random effect? The code below, results the error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ID' not found` as there is no ID in the PredDat data frame.  If I add a ID to the PredDat data frame the code runs fine.

```
Preds <- predictInterval(mod, newdata = PredDat, type = "probability")
```

Any suggests on how to generate marginal predictions from a glmer object would be greatly appreciated.

The salient session info is pasted below FYI.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

other attached packages:
[1] merTools_0.2.0          plyr_1.8.3             
[3] arm_1.8-6               MASS_7.3-45            
[5] ResourceSelection_0.2-5 lme4_1.1-10            
[7] Matrix_1.2-3            sp_1.2-1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package maintainer for `merTools` here. The way we have implemented this functionality is not really straightforward, but it is possible to do.

You need to add a step to add the median random effect to your data.frame. In most cases, the median random effect should be 0, or close enough, that it approximates what you are looking for. To do this, you need to just modify the code slightly and use the `REquantile` function from `merTools`:

```
medEff = REquantile(mod, quantile = 0.5, 
                    groupFctr = "ID", 
                    term = "(Intercept)")

PredDat <- data.frame(ELEVATION = seq(-1.97056, 2.52926, length.out = 1000),
                      SLOPE = 0, ET = 0, HLI = 0, ID = medEff)

Preds <- predictInterval(mod, newdata = PredDat, type = "probability")
```

This produces the prediction but includes uncertainty about the random effect, including the median random effect of 0. In the example above, this winds up washing out the effect of the `ELEVATION` variable across observations because the median random effect is not estimated very precisely. So, **this may not be what you want.**

Also, if you have *more complicated random effects specification* with slopes and intercepts, then this approach becomes harder because the median effect for the Intercept may be 0, but it won't be for the slope.

If you really want to just capture the variance in the prediction based on the fixed effects and their uncertainty only -- something since building the package I've learned is quite common -- there are ways to do it outside of `merTools`. This is not the most elegant, but it is what happens under the hood of `predictInterval` to get the variability of the fixed effect predictions:

```
PredDat <- data.frame(Intercept = 1, 
           ELEVATION = seq(-1.97056, 2.52926,length.out = 1000), 
           SLOPE = 0, ET = 0, HLI = 0)

 fe.tmp <- fixef(mod)
 vcov.tmp <- as.matrix(vcov(mod))
 n.sims <- 1000
 sigmahat <- rep(1, n.sims)

 # Make n.sims draws for each element of the fixed effects

 betaSim <- abind::abind(lapply(1:n.sims,
  function(x) mvtnorm::rmvnorm(n = 1, mean = fe.tmp, 
       sigma = sigmahat[x]*vcov.tmp, method = "chol")), along=1)
# Calculate n.sims predictions for each row in PredDat
fixed <- as.matrix(PredDat) %*% t(betaSim)
# For each row (observation) in PredDat calculate the median, upr and lwr 
Preds <- data.frame(fit = apply(fixed, 1, median), 
                upr = apply(fixed, 1, quantile, 0.9), 
                lwr = apply(fixed, 1, quantile, 0.1))
# Calculate the probability from the linear predictor
Preds <- apply(Preds, 2, invlogit)
```

You should get something like this:

```
head(Preds)

     fit       upr       lwr
1 0.1860053 0.2482220 0.1427370
2 0.1860058 0.2482226 0.1427373
3 0.1860062 0.2482231 0.1427377
4 0.1860066 0.2482237 0.1427380
5 0.1860071 0.2482242 0.1427384
6 0.1860075 0.2482248 0.1427388
```

This does not include any uncertainty at the observation level associated with variation in the grouping factors or in the model itself.

Comment: thanks for the informative and detailed response.  Very helpful.  Indeed, the 2nd chunk of your code is what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm going to add this as an extension to include in `merTools` in the future. It seems like a pretty easy thing for us to include in `predictInterval`